# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle

Why I just can't use these columns in select statement? Is it necessary to use such group function `GROUP BY c.CLIENT_ID,c.FNAME, c.LNAME` . How to resolve this problem?

```
 SELECT 
          c.CLIENT_ID, c.FNAME, c.LNAME, COUNT(*) 
            FROM 
              RACE r 
                JOIN VAGON v
                  ON r.RACE_ID = v.RACE_ID
                JOIN TICKET t
                  ON v.VAGON_ID = t.VAGON_ID
                JOIN CLIENT c
                  ON c.CLIENT_ID = t.CLIENT_ID
            WHERE r.DEPART_PLACE = 'Lviv' AND r.DESTINATION_PLACE = 'Kyiv';
            GROUP BY c.CLIENT_ID
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: use MAX on fname,lname.

Comment: Have you tried what you are think?

Comment: with such GROUP BY c.CLIENT_ID,c.FNAME, c.LNAME, it still doesn't work

Comment: Define: does not work.

Comment: the same error ORA-00937

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself. Yes, you need that columns in your `group by` or use an aggregation function (like `min` or `max` on it.

**Why?**

You know the row is made unique by the `Client_ID` but the database doesn't. So you have to tell it to it in order to let it determine how the query is constructed and should be executed.

And you should remove the `;` after `'Kyiv';`

Comment: It works. The main problem was missed semicolon

Comment: But it is strange why database doesn't know that CLIENT_ID is unique. Because it's primary key for table CLIENT.

Comment: It doesn't look that far. The statement should be self-explaining.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns you select should be added in the group by except the expressions.
Why?
Because the group by work in a unique way.